# View PDF security/permissions?

Tags: permissions, security, pdf

It's as simple as that: I need to view the permissions of a PDF file. Not the file system permissions, but the permissions specific to PDF Security, e.g.,

- Printing
- Document Assembly
- Content Copying
- Page Extraction
- Commenting
- Filling of Form Fields
- Signing
- Creation of Template Pages

I know I can *set* permissions and view annotations, data fields, etc. with pdftk. But I need to see what the security permissions are. A friend can do so on Mac with Acrobat Reader (I believe) and gets this:

[image: Security Permissions - Mac]

If I look at the document properties with the built-in Document Viewer (Evince), it doesn't even get the security right:

[image: Evince Document Viewer Properties]

I'm open to installing new software, but I don't need anything fancy. How can I view a PDF document's security permissions on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS?

Comment: Are both the images relating to the same pdf file?

Comment: @DKBose Yep, they are. He took the screenshot on Mac, then sent me the PDF file and the screenshot.

Comment: You can use `pypdf` for that ... and I'm thinking about adding it to `pdfly` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and type `qpdf --show-encryption filename.pdf` command to show the document's permission details.